# Can we repeat same keyword on different pages?

Tags: seo, keywords, page

Can we repeat same keyword on different pages? For example a site has tv show "example" and I am adding its 10th episode so will go with "example episode 10" keyword. Can I use the same "example" keyword on all episodes (on different pages/URLs) of the show?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can! It's really regular. For example, various big sites about tv series has one page per episode to explain the entire episode. Therefore, they use the name of the tv series on several pages.

As long as the text on pages appears natural for your users, you can do it.

Answer (score 1):

Not only *can* you, you *should* have many pages that repeat the important keywords.

A site with only one page on a topic is not going to be able to cover that topic well.   Good sites are *comprehensive*.   They cover all aspects of a topic.   That necessarily means using the keywords for the topic on many pages.

That isn't to say that you should create content *just* for the purpose of using keywords on many pages.   Write as much about a subject as that subject warrants.   Some subjects may require 5 pages and some may require 500.  Users value sites that explain the topic as simply as possible, but still have enough depth using language that a lay person can understand.    Avoid repetition and keyword stuffing that make your site look spammy and written only for search search engines.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. My site is about tv shows and aprx 4k videos of different shows, 4k videos means 4k pages. I just want to make sure that, suppose my show name is "doomsday" and it having 10 episodes (means 10 pages) so I will put two keywords for episode 1 I.e doomsday episode 1 and doomsday ep 1 can I also put only doomsday keyword on all pages/episodes ?

Comment: 20,000 questions have been asked on this site with one page for each.   There are thousands of pages with keyword such as "website", "keywords", and "seo".   Lots of pages about a topic will not hurt your site at all.

Comment: Thanks. So it mean I can repeat same keyword on  different episodes/pages

Answer (score -1):

No you can add same keyword for different pages. As gogle did not like it. Google will treat as a spam.

Comment: Like many of your other answers, this is very short on details.